# Helix 3d toolkit: How to draw a rounded cube?

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

How would I go about drawing a rounded cube, like a dice?

I have tried using `CubeVisual3D` but only seems to give 90 degree edges.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look at the chamfer or the subdivision demo provided with the toolkit